# Magento 2 Installation Fails - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database, magento, mariadb, magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 on Centos 7 using php 7.4 and MariaDB 10.5.8 . Everything works smooth just the part where I run the Magento 2 install script it throws the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '*****'@'****my ip***' (using password: YES)

In InstallCommand.php line 274:

  Parameter validation failed
```

I am able to connect to the remote DB using the mysql client from this web node where I am trying to install magento 2. Also am able to connect through any other machine or MySQL GUI tool. I just can't figure out what I am missing here. Also the password contains ! symbol so I am using black slash for escape character. Below is the script that I am running which fails:

```
bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="adminlogin" \
--key="***************************" \
--db-host="********" \
--db-name="******" \
--db-user="******" \
--db-password="*****\!***" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/New_York" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="*******" \
--base-url-secure="*******" \
--admin-user=sabbas \
--admin-password=****\!**** \
--admin-email=****** \
--admin-firstname=fname\
--admin-lastname=lname\
--cleanup-database
```

I removed the sensitive data and replaced it with * symbols. Please help. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I was able to fix the by removing the special character in the password for the db user

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be also fixed by adding quotes  '' in --db-password.

So this part should be:

> --db-password='yourpasswordwithspecialcharacter'

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the by removing the special character in the password for the db user